# Не получается отправить post запрос json

Tags: javascript, post

```
function upload() {
    var form = document.getElementById( "load" );

    var obj = {"name":"",
        "runtimeAttributes":{
            "language":"",
            "code":""
        }};

    var elements = form.querySelectorAll( "input, select" );

    obj.name = elements[0].value;

    r = obj.runtimeAttributes;
    r.language = elements[1].value;

    file = document.getElementById("code").files[0];

    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onloadend = function(event) {
        var content = event.target.result;
        r.code = content
        var json = JSON.stringify( obj, null, '  ');
        output.innerHTML = json;

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open(form.method, form.action, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/json');
        xhr.send(json);
    };

    reader.readAsText(file);

}
```

---

```
<form id = "load" method="post" action="http://localhost:8080/lambdas" onsubmit="javascript:upload()" enctype="application/json">

            <input type="text" name="name" value="helloworld">

            <select name="language">
                <option>Python3</option>
            </select>

            <input type="file" name="code" id = "code">

            <input type="submit" value="send">

    </form>
```

---

```
{"message":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException Content type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8' not supported"}
```

Comment: Попробуй `Content-type`

Comment: то же самое....

Comment: Что находится в переменой json?

Comment: попробуйте `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: в json такого вида объект
 {"name":"",
        "runtimeAttributes":{
            "language":"",
            "code":""
        }}

var json = JSON.stringify( obj, null, '  ');

Comment: пробовал, так же

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В приведённом вами коде нет ошибок, вот рабочий пример:

```js
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://httpbin.org/post', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState != 4) return;
  if (xhr.status != 200) {
    console.log(xhr.status + ': ' + xhr.statusText);
  } else {
    console.log(xhr.responseText);
  }
}

xhr.send(JSON.stringify({param: 'value'}));
```

Как видим, сервер обработал запрос корректно, и в заголовках присутствует корректный `Content-Type`.

Судя по всему? у вас на сервер уходит другой заголовок `Content-Type`, либо их несколько, ищите в коде.

Можно посмотреть актуальные заголовки запроса в `DevTools`: `F12 - вкладка Network(Сеть)`

Comment: нескольких точно нет. а можно для чайников?) как может уходить другой заголовок?

Comment: Вы в DevTools посмотрели? Что уходит? Если не `application/json`, ищите где-то в коде вы выставляете `setRequestHeader`. xhr у вас - глобальная переменная? Или всё это дело в функцию таки завёрнуто?

Comment: xhr в функции, в devtools в request стоит application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: Ну вот, теперь ищите, кто его туда пишет)

Comment: загрузил весь код, уже не знаю, куда смотреть

Comment: Ну так это совсем другая задача, у вас два запроса. Ответа от аякса вы и не ждёте, а то, где ошибка - это submit формы.

Comment: не понимаю( как это исправить?

Comment: для начала `onsubmit="upload(); return false;"`

Comment: той ошибки уже нет, а для чего это??

Comment: Только что, вы запретили нативной форме отправляться самостоятельно. Теперь вместо неё отправляется ваш аякс. Смотрите внимательно в мой ответ как обрабатывается ответ из аякс-запроса. (Тело ответа сервера это `xhr.responseText`)

Comment: спасибо большое, помогло. только теперь всплывает Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://localhost:8080/lambdas. (Причина: неудача канала CORS preflight). google что-то говорит, но я не понимаю(

Comment: Вы не можете делать запросы из браузера на другой домен, который специальным образом этого не разрешил.

Comment: то есть это установка сервера? и что значит другой домен? у меня все на локалхосте